# Mongodb: get only leaves of tree

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tree

I have a tree structure in a mongo database that fills my need. A tree node is identified by its path: a root node path is

```
#<id>
```

and a sub node describes its full hierarchy in its path:

```
#<id of parent>#<id of parent>#<id>
```

For instance I can have the following tree:

```
#a
|_#a#b
|    |_#a#b#1
|    |_#a#b#2
|_#a#c
    |_#a#c#1
          |_#a#c#1#x
```

I currently have a mean to get all children of a tree node using $regex. Applying it to

```
#a#c
```

would in this case return the following nodes

```
#a#c#1
#a#c#1#x
```

Now I am trying to find a way to find only the leaves of my tree. So applying it to the same node I would only get:

```
#a#c#1#x
```

I could get the full list then remove the 'group' elements but that would not be really clever, would it?

***Editing because question was oversimplified:***
Thank you Wan, the solution provided below answers the question I asked in case elements in the structure have a field 'parent' containing the **path** of the parent.
In my case, I have a field 'parent', but it contains the **id** of the parent, not its **path**.

The next question is how do you `connectToField` to a modified field? In my case instead of connecting to the field parent I would like to connect to `#hierarchy of parent#id of parent`

Is it possible to do some sort of preformating of the query result so that parent contains the path instead of the id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a field `parent` to capture the parent for each node, it may help to optimise querying on bigger dataset. For example:

```
{"parent": "", "node": "#a"}
{"parent": "#a", "node": "#a#b"}
{"parent": "#a", "node": "#a#c"}
{"parent": "#a#b", "node": "#a#b#1"}
{"parent": "#a#b", "node": "#a#b#2"}
{"parent": "#a#c", "node": "#a#c#1"}
{"parent": "#a#c#1", "node": "#a#c#1#x"}
```

Then you can utilise [$graphLookup (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) operator to traverse.

An alternative to your regex query to get all children of a tree node for `#a#c`:

```
db.tree.aggregate([
        {$match:{"node":"#a#c"}}, 
        {$graphLookup:{
                       from:"tree", 
                       startWith:"$node", 
                       connectFromField:"node", 
                       connectToField:"parent", 
                       as:"dep"}}, 
        {$project:{"dep.node":1, "_id":0}}
])
```

Find only leaves of `#a#c`:

```
db.tree.aggregate([
        {$match:{"parent": {$regex:"^#a#c"}}}, 
        {$graphLookup:{
                       from:"tree", 
                       startWith:"$node", 
                       connectFromField:"node", 
                       connectToField:"parent", 
                       as:"dep"}}, 
        {$match:{dep:[]}}, 
        {$project:{"_id":0, node:1}}
])
```

I would also recommend to review [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/), there are various ways to use tree data structures in MongoDB. Depending on your use case you should employ certain structures for your application querying benefits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually already do have a parent field on each node. I will have a closer look to $graphLookup and see how I can benefit from this.

Comment: Ok, I gave a try to the solution you proposed and it works perfectly fine for the question I asked. Now I have to make it a bit more difficult because I overly simplified my question. I do have a parent field, but it does not contain the path of the parent, it contains the name of the parent. I'll edit the question

Comment: @BriceMaret i think it would be best to post a new question and link the post here than changing the question.

Comment: Thank you, I did as you advised https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270370/mongodb-edit-connectfromfield-inside-graphlookup