# Mongodb: calculated connectToField inside graphlookup

Tags: mongodb, tree

I have mongo tree structure that looks like this:

```
{"parent": null, "path": "#a", "name": "a"}
{"parent": "a", "path": "#a#b", "name": "b"}
{"parent": "a", "path": "#a#c", "name": "c"}
{"parent": "b", "path": "#a#b#1", "name": "1"}
{"parent": "b", "path": "#a#b#2", "name": "2"}
{"parent": "c", "path": "#a#c#1", "name": "1"}
{"parent": "1", "path": "#a#c#1#x", "name": "x"}
```

which can be represented as follows:

```
#a
|_#a#b
|    |_#a#b#1
|    |_#a#b#2
|_#a#c
    |_#a#c#1
          |_#a#c#1#x
```

My goal is to build a request that will get only the leaves under a specified node.

Had I stored the parent path inside the field parent instead of the parent identifier I would have been able to do it using the following request:

```
db.tree.aggregate([
        {$match:{"parent": {$regex:"^#a#c"}}}, 
        {$graphLookup:{
                       from:"tree", 
                       startWith:"$path", 
                       connectFromField:"path", 
                       connectToField:"parent", 
                       as:"dep"}}, 
        {$match:{dep:[]}}, 
        {$project:{"_id":0, path:1}}
])
```

as already answered in my previous question here:
[Mongodb: get only leaves of tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163177/mongodb-get-only-leaves-of-tree)

The problem is I did not.

So I have to somehow transform the 'connectToField' in my request so that it represents the path of my parent instead of the id of my parent.
Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`connectToField` is a name, not an expression. You can't do anything with it.

You really need to re-consider the schema. It is flawed in many ways starting from non-unique names used in parent references. Since you rely on the path string instead <sub><sup>(which is a questionable decision by itself)</sup></sub>, you need a path to reference the parent.

**The answer below does it runtime, and is hardly advisable for operational queries due to performance inefficiency** and some assumptions of how the path is built. It can be used as a one-off request though.

Basically you need to create a [view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/index.html) with calculated parent path:

```
db.createView("rootless_tree", "tree", [
    { $match: { parent: { $ne: null } } },
    { $addFields: {
        parent_path: { $let: {
            vars: { parents: { $split: [ "$path", "#" ] } },
            in: { $reduce: {
                input: { $slice: [ "$$parents", 1, { $subtract: [ { $size: "$$parents" }, 2 ] } ] },
                initialValue: "",
                in: { $concat: [ "$$value", "#", "$$this" ] }
            } }
        } }
    } }
]);
```

So then you can do your lookup as advised in your previous question:

```
db.tree.aggregate([
    { $graphLookup: {
        from: "rootless_tree", 
        startWith: "$path", 
        connectFromField: "path", 
        connectToField: "parent_path", 
        as:"dep"
    } },
    { $match: { dep: [] } },                       
])
```

Comment: Understood, thank you for your answer. I may be able to make your solution work on a limited scope of my data. And no worries, I did not use the names as unique identifiers, I used only objectids and paths are automatically rebuilt when a parent is changed: I used names in my question just to make it easier to read, I admit it was not a good idea. So is there a better solution as the parent field actually refers to a unique node (and not to a name as described in my question)?

Comment: But of course. All this mess is because you have 2 nodes with `name: 1`, and you explicitly said in this follow up question that `parent` holds the `name` of the parent node. Since the name is not unique it makes it impossible to use it for references. Please try to *simplify* questions reasonably. Otherwise you keep getting answers that solves the problem posted in the question, not the one you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you, question rewritten and reposted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307575/mongodb-compute-a-value-before-using-it-as-connectfromfield-in-an-aggregate